# Calculus in one real variable

Tags: calculus

> Let $f$ be differentiable at a point $a$. Prove that $$g(a,h) = \dfrac{f(a + h) - f(a - h)}{2h} \to f^\prime (a)$$ as $h \to 0$. Construct an example to show $g(a,h) \to 1$ as $h \to 0$ but $f$ is not differentiable at $a$.

I have proved the first part of the question  but I can't find any $f$ for the last part of the  question.

Comment: ¿Could you show us how you have proved the first part? This would give us a hint about what you know and how you reason.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Note that the definition of $g$ is independent of the value of $f$ at $a$. But certainly the definition of $f'(a)$ is not.

Comment: How shoud i choose f so that g satisfies the desired condition but f'(a) is not defined

Comment: Pick any differentiable function with the desired value for its derivative at $a$, then change the value of the function at $a$ so it isn't differentiable there any more. Using $g$ will reproduce the original derivative at that point, but the modified function is no longer differentiable there.

Answer (score 0):

In part 1) you should have shown that

$\lim_\limits{h\to0} g(a,h) = \frac 12\lim_\limits{x\to a^+} f'(x) +\frac 12 \lim_\limits{x\to a^-} f'(x)$

Now you need a function $f$ such that: $\lim_\limits{x\to a^+} f'(x) \ne  \lim_\limits{x\to a^-} f'(x)$

and $\frac 12\lim_\limits{x\to a^+} f'(x) + \frac 12  \lim_\limits{x\to a^-} f'(x) = 1$

$f(x) = \begin{cases} 2x &x\ge 0\\0&x<0 \end{cases}$

is such a function

Comment: for this function f'(a)  certainly doesnt exist but i cant prove the desired property for g

Comment: Sure you can!  $\lim_\limits{h\to 0} g(0,h)  = \frac {2h - 0}{2h} = 1$

Comment: Can we find some function  f such that these conditions hold for any arbitrary point instead  of  zero

Comment: How about:  f(x) = |x-a| + x

Comment: @DougM Note that the condition on lateral limits is **not** the only way to make the function non-differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $\;f(x)=|1-x|.$

Comment: Now I am able to solve the problem completely thanks a lot for valuable help